# Organizing numbers until 0 0 0 is entered

Tags: c

hello i made a program that organizes 3 numbers that user submits . the program works but for some reason when i put 0 0 0 it does not finish .

```
while (k == 1)
    {
        k=inputthree(&num1, &num2, &num3);
        if (k == 1)
        {
            sortthree(&num1, &num2, &num3);
            printf("%d %d %d\n", num1, num2, num3);
        }else printf("Finish!");
```

inputthree seems to always return 1 i dont know why . the full code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
int inputthree(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3);
void sorttwo(int* num1, int* num2);
void sortthree(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3);
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3,k=1;
    while (k == 1)
    {
        k=inputthree(&num1, &num2, &num3);
        if (k == 1)
        {
            sortthree(&num1, &num2, &num3);
            printf("%d %d %d\n", num1, num2, num3);
        }else printf("Finish!");
    }
}
int inputthree(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3)
{
    printf("Enter 3 numbers:- ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", num1, num2, num3);
    if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0 && num3 == 0)
        return 0;
    else return 1;

}
void sorttwo(int* num1, int* num2)
{
    int temp;
    if (*num1 > *num2)
    {
        temp = *num1;
        *num1 = *num2;
        *num2 = temp;
    }

}
void sortthree(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3)
{
    sorttwo(num1, num2);
    sorttwo(num1, num3);
    sorttwo(num2, num3);


}
```

***Thanks everyone for your help.***

Comment: `num1 == 0 && num2 == 0 && num3 == 0` --> `*num1 == 0 && *num2 == 0 && *num3 == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking whether the all parameters are `NULL` in the scope of `inputthree`. Try,

```
if(*num1 == 0 && *num2 == 0 && *num3 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the pointers, not the nums. Use:

```
if(*num1 == 0 && *num2 == 0 && *num3 == 0)
```